# Data for on/off-the-run treasury spreads

Tags: data-request, bonds

I would like to find the latest data for the spread between on-the-run and off-the-run treasuries. Not too picky about the tenor, maybe 2yrs and a few longer ones. I've come across [a Fed paper](https://www.newyorkfed.org/medialibrary/media/research/epr/03v09n3/0309flempdf.pdf) and found basically what I was looking for:

[image]

However, in St. Louis Fred data, I was unable to find this series, which leads me to think this may be for Fed's internal use and not disclosed to the public.

### Question

Is there a public domain source for this data, or might we be able to derive it from other series on the St Louis Fred website?

Comment: The graph says it uses data from Bear Stearns and GovPX, so these are not Feds publicly available datasets, Fred website is thus wrong place to look for the data. I would start with websites of Bear Stearns and GovPX